# I receive a data type mismatch error when I filter sparklyr DataFrame

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I am attempting to iterate and create spark data frames in sparklyr.

I have a list of ids that I want to loop through and create data frames according to the group. The original datatype of the column in spark is an integer and when I attempt to create data frames in a loop I get the following error.

```
Error : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(nbugheympj.`id`
```

Code:

```
for (id_elem in id_list)
                  { 
                  df_filter<- df%>%dplyr::filter(id == id_elem)
```

Even when I attempt to cast the column to a string I still get the error.

```
df_final<- df%>%dplyr::mutate(id_str = as.character(id))

for (id_elem in id_list)
                  { id_str_elem = as.character(id_elem);
                  peloton_filter<- df_final%>%dplyr::filter(id_str == id_str_elem) ;
```

Comment: it does appear that the column 'id' is not there, please try to provide a reproducible example, here is an older question about sparklyr  where I provide one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890412/calculating-order-statistics-percentile-using-sparklyr